# How do I start an Activity with the HomeButton of the ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, start-activity

At the moment i use this code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

, but now the Button shouldnt be only a back-function. I like to start an other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I know i should use the `setOnClickListener`, but I don't know where i call the Listener.

Comment: So your goal is to confuse your users by using the up button in a non-standard way?

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Tanis.7x comment, you shouldn't be using that button if it's not to go back by calling `finish()` or `popBackStack()`,

the action for the home button is called with the menu options

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked;

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```